# Sequelize - How to get a list of nested table entries (Project -> Task through Milestones)?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Lets say I have the tables User, Project, Milestone, Task

```
User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: ProjectUser})
Project.belongsToMany(User, {through: ProjectUser})

Project.hasMany(Milestone)
Milestone.belongsTo(Project)

Milestone.hasMany(Task)
Task.belongsTo(Milestone)
```

Now I can easily get all Milestones in a Project where a User belongs to:

```
User.findAll({
    include: [{ 
        model: Project,
        include: [{
            model: Milestone
            include: [ Task ]
        }]
    }]
```

Now I would like to get the Tasks not inside the Milestones. Instead I would like to get the Tasks parallel to Milestones. Like this:

```
User.findAll({
    include: [{ 
        model: Project,
        include: [
            Milestone,
            Task
        ]
    }]
```

But if I do it like this I get as expected:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Task is not associated to Project!
```

I could use a Project.hasMany(Task) but then I would need to add a ProjectId column to the Task table. I would like to avoid that. So I thought about

```
Project.belongsToMany(Task, { through: Milestone })
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column Projects.Tasks.Milestones.TaskId does not exist
```

I know that and Milestones can't contain a TaskId as Milestones have multiple Tasks. So the reference between Milestone and Task is stored in Task as MilestoneId.

Anyone a Idea how I get a List with all Tasks which belong to the Project without adding a ProjectId to Tasks??

Comment: how about `Task.belongsTo(Project, { through: Milestone })`?

Comment: Then I still get an error, as the Task knows about the Project but the Project is does not know about the task..  Unhandled rejection Error: Task is not associated to Project!

Comment: I am facing the same problem did you managed to solve this?